# Update another string from custom editable UITableViewCell - pass by reference in swift?

Tags: ios, parameter-passing

I made a class from UITableViewCell that allows me to edit the right detail text. It uses a UITextField as the editableAccessoryView. Code below.

The problem is I need to update a string based on the change. I.e. when editing is finished the string will be updated with the textField.text string.

In another language I might have a String pointer in the UITableViewCell subclass which I would update with the pointer of the string I wanted to change. But although I can pass a pointer to a function using `inout` I cant work out how to store that pointer.

Any ideas?

```
import UIKit

class EditableRightDetailTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    enum TextFieldType {
        case Text
        case Numeric
    }

    var type = TextFieldType.Text

    let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(150, 7, 200, 30))

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
        textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
        textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
        textField.delegate = self
        self.editingAccessoryView = textField
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {

        if !self.editing && editing == true {
            self.detailTextLabel?.hidden = true
            textField.text = self.detailTextLabel?.text
        }
        else if self.editing && editing == false {
            self.detailTextLabel?.hidden = false
            self.detailTextLabel?.text = textField.text
        }
        super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
    }

    func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        if type == TextFieldType.Numeric {
            // We ignore any change that doesn't add characters to the text field.
            // These changes are things like character deletions and cuts, as well
            // as moving the insertion point.
            //
            // We still return true to allow the change to take place.
            if count(string) == 0 {
                return true
            }

            // Check to see if the text field's contents still fit the constraints
            // with the new content added to it.
            // If the contents still fit the constraints, allow the change
            // by returning true; otherwise disallow the change by returning false.
            let prospectiveText = (textField.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

            return prospectiveText.isNumeric() && count(prospectiveText) <= 11
        }
        return true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bad practice**

You really do not want to keep pointers to objects in a `UITableViewCell`. First of all, they are generally cached by the OS, and loaded on demand, In short, you should not attempt to own them, and certainly retain pointers inside.

**Good practice**

If your data changes, tell the `UITableView` to redraw that cell. You may even redraw a new, different `UITableViewCell` in place. (*You could even use a notification, to decouple your view even further from the model*)

**Swift**

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: row, inSection: section)
self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

**Obj-C**

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
NSIndexPath * indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean even with a single character change I should update the model variable which is the source for the values for the UITableViewCell generated in cellForRowAtIndexPath? Previously I have done this by making the TableViewController a delegate for the editingTextFields, giving each text field a unique tag, and implementing textFieldDidEndEditing to save the values to the model using the tags to differentiate.

Comment: What is the best way to update the model variable after editing is finished? Any way to keep the delegate functionality within the UITextViewCell subclass or should I make another class?

Comment: An alternative is to use a static cell, and hold on to it. Ways to create a static cell is to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` with a unique id. That way, you are guaranteed to get the same cell over and over. Event so, you should refrain from directly holding on to it, and ensure it is cleaned properly. Yes, the only way to do this is to subclass `UITableViewCell`, which is easy enough, even or especially if you are using `Storyboard`. Additionally, I you are using `Storyboard`, you can drag references to your subviews onto your subclass. Just be mindful of the objects life cycles.

Comment: To clarify further, I consider dangerous to attempt to hold on to a pointer to your cell, and make external references to it: you should let the OS dictate the lifecycle of table view cells, headers and footers.

Comment: If I used static cells, the only references to the cell will be in the ViewController. Using dynamic cells I don't hold on to any references. All I need to happen is when the table editing is done (editing shows textFields that can be changed) the model variable is updated. Most people seem to do this by setting the TextField delegate to the ViewController and using the TextField tag to determine which model variable to update. This clutters the ViewController code though. This is what I've done at the moment:

Comment: 1. Make a subclass of `NSObject` and `UITextViewDelegate` with a single String variable. The class implements `textFieldDidEndEditing` which simply copies the textField string to the String variable. 2. Make a subclass of `UITextViewCell` with some logic to show a `UITextField` if editing is enabled, and fire endEditing on the `UITextField` when editing is stopped. 3. I make a bunch of the `UITextViewDelegate` subclass for each variable.

Comment: 4. in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in the ViewController I use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` to make one of the custom cells and set the `UITextField` delegate on each cell to the relevant `UITextViewDelegate` subclass instance. 5. When editing is finished I copy the values from the `UITextViewDelegate` subclass instances to the model variables

Comment: Now if a pointer to an object in a cell was always refreshed on the call to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` would it really matter if it was cached?

Comment: That seems sound. As long as your delegate points to an upper hierarchy object, you are good to go.

Comment: I added my current solution as an answer. Would be interested in your comments - it seems to work quite well but there may be some issue I'm not seeing (am writing my first ios app here)

Answer (score 0):

He is my implementation if any one is interested:

The editable UITextViewCell. It should be set as Right Detail in IB. When the table view is set to editing a UITextField will appear.

```
import UIKit

class EditableRightDetailTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    let textField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(150, 7, 200, 30))

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.RoundedRect
        textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
        textField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
        self.editingAccessoryView = textField
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    func initWithValues(label: String, detail: String) {
        self.textLabel!.text = label
        self.detailTextLabel?.text = detail
        textField.text = detail
    }

    override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {

        if !self.editing && editing == true {
            self.detailTextLabel?.hidden = true
            textField.text = self.detailTextLabel?.text
        }
        else if self.editing && editing == false {
            self.detailTextLabel?.hidden = false
            self.detailTextLabel?.text = textField.text
            textField.endEditing(true)
        }
        super.setEditing(editing, animated: false)
    }
}
```

And here is the delegate. Note the value changed variable. It can be assigned a closure to run when ever the value is updated

```
import UIKit

class StringFieldDelegate: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var value: String

    var valueChanged: Optional<() -> ()> = nil
    func invokeValueChanged() {
        self.valueChanged?()
    }

    init(value: String) {
        self.value = value
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        value = textField.text
        invokeValueChanged()
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        value = textField.text
        invokeValueChanged()
        return true
    }
}
```

Then in the `ViewController` we create variables like

```
var nameField: StringFieldDelegate!
```

and initialise them in `viewDidLoad`

In the cell loading part we can set the delegate of the cell

```
cell.textField.delegate = nameField
```

And now nameField will get updated when ever the cell is finished editing or return is pressed. (For instant update you have to implement `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` and update the value and fire `invokeValueChanged` in there)

Also you can assign a closure for when ever the value changes, e.g.

```
nameField.valueChanged = { println(nameField.value) }
```

The delegate can be used for any UITextField. If you implement `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` you can do things like:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        if count(string) == 0 {
            return true
        }
        let prospectiveText = (textField.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

        return prospectiveText.isNumeric()
    }
```

which will make the text field only accept numeric characters, using the extension

```
extension String {

    // Returns true if the string represents a proper numeric value.
    // This method uses the device's current locale setting to determine
    // which decimal separator it will accept.
    func isNumeric() -> Bool
    {
        let scanner = NSScanner(string: self)

        // A newly-created scanner has no locale by default.
        // We'll set our scanner's locale to the user's locale
        // so that it recognizes the decimal separator that
        // the user expects (for example, in North America,
        // "." is the decimal separator, while in many parts
        // of Europe, "," is used).
        scanner.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()

        return scanner.scanDecimal(nil) && scanner.atEnd
    }

}
```